# FPGA Floating-point to Unsigned 32bits

Tags: fpga, xilinx, floating-point

Regarding something I read in a Xilinx manual saying this:

> Because floating-point operations use considerable resources relative to integer/fixed point operations, the Vivado HLS tool utilizes those resources as efficiently as possible.

I was thinking about the following option:

If that is true about floating-point cores utilizing more resources, why can't we convert every float we have to u32 with a union like this:

```
union converter{
     float f32;
     unsigned int u32;
}
```

do the operations always with the u32 and then in the end convert everything back to float?

I saw some examples of people doing this in really small designs, but never in big ones with lots of float operations.

Comment: What sort of operations would you perform on such a union?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just because they use the same number of bits, doesn't mean that you can perform operations on them in the same way.

Look at how a float is actually constructed internally - how the bits are used (sign, exponent, fraction) and then think about what would happen if you simply did integer operations on it.

[image]

Comment: Yeap, I was confusing operations with conversions only. Sorry guys and ty

Comment: Of course, if you _do_ manage to design a working floating-point algorithm based on simple integer operations, [the results can be mind-blowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root).

Answer (score 5):

You can, but if you do, you cannot perform any floating point operations, so it wouldn't help you in calculations.  Floating point calculations are time consuming.  Load/Store operations aren't.